# Align shapes with css :before, :after

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to make shapes in the :before/ :after . this works fine in chrome but in Firefox. there is a small misalignment. and while printing that causes a small white space between the element and the :after selector.

This is how it looks in print preview with Firefox

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My CSS

```
/* Styles go here */

.container .topbar {
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #91C34F !important;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.container .topbar .text {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff !important;
  float: right;
  top: 3px;
  background-color: #91C34F !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 80px;
}

.container .topbar .text:after {
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5px;
  left: -37px;
  border-right: 38px solid #91C34F !important;
  border-bottom: 34px solid transparent;
}
```

This is a plunk for above code https://plnkr.co/edit/oll1ooap2mKC1EQo0n84?p=preview.

How to make that align properly in all browsers?

Comment: Try Using a CSS Reset --- https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: will try that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use equal value for `left`, `border-right` and `border-bottom`, also there is nothing like `.5px`.
use `line-height` to make text vertical align.

[updated plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/TlKaJQ5UF1ZQ5hOew8SG?p=preview)

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container .topbar {
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #91C34F !important;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.container .topbar .text {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff !important;
  float: right;
  top: 3px;
  background-color: #91C34F !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px 80px;
  height:34px;
  line-height:28px;
}

.container .topbar .text:after {
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -34px;
  border-right: 34px solid #91C34F !important;
  border-bottom: 34px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you. but there is always a white space when printed with Firefox. can be a browser bug rite.

Comment: @SibiRaj you can try to patch it with a shadow on `.text {box-shadow:: -2px 0 1px -1px #91C34F `  or try another method :  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LjriC (pseudo is on top and hides parts of the container instead making it look bigger)

Answer (score 0):

1. Take http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ to heart. Looking good is a sensible goal, looking the same isn't.
2. Understand the standards (we never know if the difference is because of a bug or because you've provided instructions that only make sense for a particular window size)
3. Use them (don't forget to validate the HTML and CSS and to lint the JS)
4. Ensure you engage standards mode
5. Learn about bugs in browsers

Though your code is right, it works perfectly on chrome.
Do check here,

https://jsfiddle.net/djmayank/q20e6u9m/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container .topbar {
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #91C34F !important;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.container .topbar .text {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff !important;
  float: right;
  top: 3px;
  background-color: #91C34F !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 80px;
}

.container .topbar .text:after {
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5px;
  left: -37px;
  border-right: 38px solid #91C34F !important;
  border-bottom: 34px solid transparent;
}
```

Hope it helped.